# Get iframe content when showing error document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, browser

**Question first:**
Is it possible to get iframe contents when it's displaying a browser error document (page not found, connection lost, certificate problem...)?

**Problem explained:**
I've built a simple form with an iframe inside. This iframe has a simple file upload form that works great in every test I have done. BUT the form is meant to be used inside a company's network and some users are reporting random problems when sending the iframe upload form from inside the network. I suspect that they are receaving lost connections because of internal network malfunctions and *the iframe gets blank after sending (because the size is too small to display the error document and scrollbars are disabled)*.

As I'm not able to reproduce the errors I need to debug the process with Javascript, logging what is loaded inside the iframe after an error occurs to a user.

Actually I use jQuery to retrieve iframe's content:

```
$("#iframeid").contents().find("body").html();
```

Works great when retrieving a regular html document but not when trying to retrieve a browser error document. In this case I get the error:

`Permission denied to access property "document"`

Why is this happening? Because of same origin policy? Is there any way to override this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is this happening? Because of same origin policy?

Yes.

> Is there any way to override this?

No.

The browser does not allow you to read the contents of an internal document, like a 404 page. You will want to configure your webserver or fastcgi to return a soft 404 page which would allow you to view the contents of the iframe.

Comment: Thanks. As I suspected. I have no way to access company's server config. Will try other interface solutions.